# Read new mails from sent items using IMAP

Tags: python, email, gmail, imap

I'm trying to retrieve new mails from sent mail folder of Gmail using IMAP, but in the sent folder every messages are has the \Seen flag set. So I cannot retrieve the latest messages in the folder.

```
imap_conn.select("[Gmail]/Sent Mail")

typ, data = imap_conn.search(None,since_date,'UnSeen')
```

Do anyone have idea for how to retrieve the new mails from sent folder?

Comment: Did you try your code with a different IMAP server?

Comment: The index numbers I believe are monotonously increasing. Keep track of the index of the last message you read, and retrieve any with a higher index number.

Comment: If you delete(expunge) a message the index numbers of other messages change, so it would probably be safer to keep track of message UID's or internaldate timestamps

Answer (score 3):

For the name to use for your 'Sent Items' folders check:

```
mail.list()
```

Make sure you use the extra quotes in your string, e.g.:

```
imap_conn.select('"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"')
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although less efficient then Gryphius' answer, you create a custom IMAP flag and then mark all the message you have seen with that custom flag.

Here is an example from SO:
[javamail: Setting custom flags on imap mail and searching for mails with custom flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278234/javamail-setting-custom-flags-on-imap-mail-and-searching-for-mails-with-custom)