# javamail: Setting custom flags on imap mail and searching for mails with custom flags

Tags: java, email, imap, jakarta-mail

Is it possible to set custom flags on IMAP mail messages using java mail without overwriting existing flags? Eg, I need to set a flag "processed" on processed messages without changing its state to SEEN / DELETED or without mail clients interfering with this "processed" flag.

Then I need to find all mail that doesn't have the "processed" flag and process them after which they are also flagged as "processed".

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Flags processedFlag = new Flags("processed");
folder.setFlags(msgs, processedFlag, true);
// or
msg.setFlags(processedFlag, true);
```

Not all IMAP servers will support these "user flags", but most will.  To find messages without this flag:

```
Message[] msgs = folder.search(new FlagTerm(processedFlag, false));
```

Comment: How can we get the limit of custom mail flags per mailbox?

Comment: Does it supported by exchange server?

Comment: There's no standard way to get the limit on flags.  I believe Exchange does support user flags.

Comment: I found it here, it seems that exchange does not support: http://serverfault.com/questions/115769/which-imap-flags-are-reliably-supported-across-most-mail-servers, its permanent flag does not contain \\*.