# IMAP, setting custom mail flag support on exchange server?

Tags: java, email, exchange-server, imap, flags

Is the example below (java, java mail api) supported by exchange server? Does exchange server support setting custom mail flags?

[javamail: Setting custom flags on imap mail and searching for mails with custom flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278234/javamail-setting-custom-flags-on-imap-mail-and-searching-for-mails-with-custom)

```
Flags processedFlag = new Flags("processed");
folder.setFlags(msgs, processedFlag, true);
// or
msg.setFlags(processedFlag, true);
```

Comment: I don't believe so, but I don't have hard data about this.  Is `\*` in the `PERMANENTFLAGS` response?  This is how the protocol indicates whether custom flags are supported or not.

Comment: Does this help?  http://serverfault.com/questions/115769/which-imap-flags-are-reliably-supported-across-most-mail-servers

Comment: Totally what i was looking for.